# What is the best way to obtain many/multiple POST variables in PHP from serialize() AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

I have a form with many many inputs and I use the following code to send all my form data to php proccesing:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="a" />
<input type="text" name="b" />
<input type="text" name="c" />
<input type="text" name="d" />
<input type="text" name="e" />
<input type="text" name="f" />
<button type="button" onclick="update()">UPDATE</button>
</form>

<!-- HERE I SHOW THE VALUES FROM ABOVE INPUTS -->
<input type="text" id="a" />
<input type="text" id="b" />
<input type="text" id="c" />
<input type="text" id="d" />
<input type="text" id="e" />
<input type="text" id="f" />
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
function update()
{
    var str = $("form").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "update.php",  
        data: str,  
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) 
        {  
            document.getElementById("a").value = result.a;
            document.getElementById("b").value = result.b;
            document.getElementById("c").value = result.c;
            document.getElementById("d").value = result.d;
            document.getElementById("e").value = result.e;
            document.getElementById("f").value = result.f;
        },
        error: function(result){
            console.log("Error:");
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    // return false;
}

</script>
```

AND update.php:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = $_POST['c'];
$a = $_POST['d'];
$b = $_POST['e'];
$c = $_POST['f'];

$arr = array(
'a' => $a, 
'b' => $b, 
'c' => $c,
'a' => $d, 
'b' => $e, 
'c' => $f
);

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

1. First question:
   Is there a simple method of passing all serialize() variables in PHP, instead of writing all of them like I did in my code? There are too many and I think is is not OK that I have to manually add all of them.

   > ```
   >  $a = $_POST['a'];
   >  $b = $_POST['b'];
   >  $c = $_POST['c'];
   >  $d = $_POST['d'];
   >  $e = $_POST['e'];
   >  $f = $_POST['f'];
   > ```
2. Is there a short way to pass ajax result array values from PHP in multiple  inputs, instead of using the following code?

> ```
> document.getElementById("a").value = result.a;
>  document.getElementById("b").value = result.b;
>  document.getElementById("c").value = result.c;
>  document.getElementById("d").value = result.d;
>  document.getElementById("e").value = result.e;
>  document.getElementById("f").value = result.f;
> ```

All I am trying to say that I have too many inputs on the form and I don't want to add those variables manually. It takes too much time and it is easy to mistake at getting id's and names.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your form inputs as array instead of individual name.. Meaning

```
<input name='form[a]' type='text'/>
 <input name='form[b]' type='text'/>
 <input name='form[c]' type='text'/>
 <input name='form[d]' type='text'/>
```

Then in php do this

```
echo(json_encode($_POST['form']));
```

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks.